# PL/SQL call to procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, procedure, procedures

I wrote a PL/SQL procedure to update the salary of the table Employee

```
create table Employee
(ID                 VARCHAR2(4 BYTE)         NOT NULL,
First_Name         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
   Last_Name          VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
   Start_Date         DATE,
   End_Date           DATE,
    Salary             Number(8,2),
   City               VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    Description        VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
)
 /
```

And this is the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_employee_salary(
   p_factor IN NUMBER
    ) AS
    v_employee_count INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        UPDATE employee
       SET salary = salary * p_factor;
       COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       ROLLBACK;
   END update_employee_salary;
   /
```

When I try to call the procedure

```
CALL update_employee_salary (1.5)
```

oracle displays `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`

Comment: How are you calling the procedure?  From SQL\*Plus?  JDBC?  ODP.NET?  SQL Developer?  Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is incorrect way of calling `procedure`. You can use the below method :

```
    Begin
    update_employee_salary(1.5);
    End;
```

Read more here : [PL/SQL Procedure](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_procedures.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can also execute it like this, in SQL*PLUS and SQL-Developer:

```
EXEC update_employee_salary(1.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a procedure with CALL  as you did. The reason for not working could be related to a previous sql statement that hasn't been closed with ;. Moreover a piece of advice: you should not use oracle/plsql reserved words as table column name as you did (id is a reserved word).